# How do I put text within a pre-existing border

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a tribute page and I have an image in a border but I also want to add text inside the border underneath the image.

I have tried putting the text and image in the same class css and giving them the same id.

```css
#image {
  max-width: 400px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  padding: 50px;
}

.border {
  border: 5px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" class="border" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" <figcaption id="img-caption" class="border"><em><a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug target="_blank"> Dr. Norman Borlaug</a>, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</em></figcaption>
</div>
```

I'm expecting the image and picture to be within the same border but they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your class at individual elements. You need to provide the class border to the outer div and also remove the border css from the image itself.

Since you are providing border class and/or border style to individual elements. It appears around them.

```css
#image {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.border {
  border: 5px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <img id="image" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" />
  <figcaption id="img-caption">
    <em>
        <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug target="_blank"> Dr. Norman Borlaug
        </a>, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.   
    </em>
  </figcaption>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, wrap all in a div with a border:

```
<div class="border">
<img id="image"  src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" 
         <figcaption id="img-caption" class="border"><em><a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug target="_blank"> Dr. Norman Borlaug</a>, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</em></figcaption>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figcaption is it's own block and will need the img tag to close before it. Then just wrap the whole thing in a div.

```css
.border {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<img id="image" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg" />
  <figcaption id="img-caption" class="border">
    <em><a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug target="_blank"> Dr. Norman Borlaug</a>, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</em>
   </figcaption>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around the image and text and then apply to border to that div.

```css
.border {
    max-width:400px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    padding: 50px;
}
.border img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <img id="image" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3689/10613180113_fdf7bcd316_b.jpg"> 
  <figcaption id="img-caption">
    <em><a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug target="_blank"> Dr. Norman Borlaug</a>, third from the left, trains biologists in Mexico on how to increase wheat yields - part of his life-long war on hunger.</em>
    </figcaption>
</div>
```